# What is the best way to measure and record the power consumption of a servo motor accurately?

Tags: power, motor, current-measurement, torque, power-consumption

I can obtain the rotational angle and velocity of a servo motor. However, I cannot obtain the current nor torque while the motor is turning. What is the best way to measure the power consumption of a servo motor when it is turning?

Comment: You need an oscilloscope with a current probe or shunt.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean using an oscilloscope to obtain the voltage and a current probe or shunt to obtain the current during the experiment. Then, multiply the values using P=VI? Is the reason for using an oscilloscope to measure the voltage is that voltage drops over time? Any suggestion on good and small current probe or shunt? Not a must but ideally with storage capability.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information.  What sort of motor is utilized?  What sort of power consumption do you *expect*?   Are you looking to conduct a bench test, or build in something which will report data in operation?   Have you considered how the current will vary depending on the mechanical load?  If the drive amplifier is switching, do you want to see the current profile of the actual pulses or do you want an average?

Comment: @lovedrinking You need a current probe that plugs into an oscilloscope so the current waveform can be on the scope along with the voltage. A shunt is just a low value resistor that can handle high power, and is stable over a wide temperature. Remember that if your shunt is not ground-referenced and your scope is measuring other voltages at the same time, then you need to use a differential probe on the shunt. Non-invasive hall-sensor type probes can be really friggin' expensive so I think you are better off with a differential probe which has more uses than just current measurement.

Comment: The reason you need the waveform and use a scope is because the servo is not operating in steady state.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks. What value of shunt should I get? How to connect it to the system so that it is ground-referenced? I have a digital oscilloscope but the probes are not differential.

Comment: @lovedrinking Ground referenced just means that if you measure the voltage across the shunt, you are measuring with respect to ground. In other words, one of the shunt terminals is connected to ground (the shunt is the last the thing the conventional current flows through in the circuit before returning to the power source). Shunt value depends on sensitivity vs current levels. It is a tradeoff. When ground-referenced, you want it to be especially low since the more current that flows, the more every other voltage in the circuit gets raised. Values are often a few milliOhms or less.

Comment: And an amplifier is often used to amplify the voltage across the shunt prior to reading.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen. Sorry, I am still a bit confused about how to connect between the motor, power source, oscilloscope and current probe/shunt/current sensor. Is there some kind of picture?

Comment: Low-side current sensing: https://www.escomponents.com/precision-current-sensing

Answer (score 1):

> measure the power consumption of a servo motor when it is turning

For this you need to measure the voltage (U) and the amperage (I) at the same time and over time.

That will give you the power consumption (P = U x I)

But the power consumption will vary depending on what phase the servo is in, start, stop and different loads.

So the best way is to log the measurements over time so you can get a accurate overview over the power consumption. This can be achieved with a multi meter with data output, a oscilloscope with logging function or a DIY Arduino (example [http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut84.php)](http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut84.php)

The best solution depends on what you need to measure (mAmps or Amps) and on your wallet and knowledge.

**PS.** Next time add more data and you will get a more accurate answer.